# Do we require a new snapshot in Transactional Replication after changing the location of mdf n ldf files?

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, database-administration

It is my prod environment...I have a transactional replication on going for a db and now I'm changing my ldf and mdf file location using attach method then in that process we have to take our database offline and then bring it online again.
So my major concern is if we move the location of ldf and mdf files then will my Transactional Replication break? Or if it does not break then will I have to take another snapshot of the DB to continue the sync?

Is it even possible to take database offline or move mdf ldf files when database is in transactional replication?

Please help me with these question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. Replication knows which commands to deliver to a subscriber based on LSN. So long as the distributor stop has the commands to deliver, it will pick up where it left of. Just make sure that your distribution cleanup settings are set to longer than you anticipate being offline and you'll be fine.

Check out the MS article on backup/restore for replication databases [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/administration/strategies-for-backing-up-and-restoring-snapshot-and-transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thank you for your resonse.It is taking too long for a database in replication to take offline. Is it even possible to take database offline without disabling the replication?

Comment: I don't think there's anything special. How are you taking the database offline? If it were me, I'd stop the distribution agent (since that's in your control) and then issue an `alter database «your db» set offline with rollback immediate`.

Comment: I stopped the jobs and then tried to modify the file location. After modification, I made the database offline followed by moving the mdf & ldf files to the new location and then bring back the database online. But while bringing the database online it is throwing an error that the file location is unable to find. Do you know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Here's what I have tried till now:                                                                                  alter database DB4_SUB

 
modify file (name = 'DB4_SUB', filename = 'C:\Data\DB4_SUB.mdf')
 
Go
 
alter database DB4_SUB
 
modify file (name = 'DB4_SUB_log', filename = 'C:\Data\DB4_SUB_log.ldf')
 
 
alter database [DB2_Subscriber] set online
 
 
USE [master];
GO
ALTER DATABASE DB4_SUB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
 
ALTER DATABASE DB4_SUB SET OFFLINE;
 
ALTER DATABASE DB4_SUB SET ONLINE;